# last steps before beta testing / submission to app store?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I'm a newbie.  I've worked out all the bugs I can find in my app, but before I find beta testers and ultimately submit to the app store, I want to make sure I don't leave out any important steps.  For example, I see several questions talking about checking for memory leaks, but I don't really know what that is or how to do it; same thing with the sandbox.  I've already created a signing certificate and a provisioning profile and registered my device.

So:  assuming that my code is all working, what else should I do or check for?

(If this isn't an appropriate stackoverflow.com question, I apologize; please let me know, and I'll remove it asap.)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely check for leaks.

Leaks are where your app doesn't give up memory to the system after it has finished using it. This can mean (a) Your app uses more memory than it needs to and (2) the device runs out of memory if your app runs for a long time, and your app can crash and other apps will be closed.

Here's a guide to finding leaks, using a tool called Instruments that comes with Xcode.
http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/

Also make sure you write 'review notes' for the reviewer if there's any aspect of your app that won't be immediately obvious. If you need a login to use the app, make sure you provide a test one in the review notes. Consider making a (private?) YouTube video showing the app in action.